# How to get the value/text change event of any html element (especially labels) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    **$(document).ready(function(){
        $(':input').keypress(function(e) {
            $('h1').text($(':input').val());
        });
        $('h1').change( function() {
            alert('hao');
        });
    });**
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        **<h1></h1>
        <input type="text" />**
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i have a text box on keypress in textbox the value of textbox goes into the heading element...but i've used function "$('h1').change ..." and it should execute when the value of heading changes, but it's not. i want that event to carry out a process, please suggest some loop overs.

Comment: also in your :input keypress function you use $(':input').val(), but that wouldn't make sense if you have multiple inputs, so I suggest using $('h1').text($(this).val());

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a `change` event to a non-form element!!

See: http://api.jquery.com/change/

> The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements.

The following code will not work:

```
$('h1').change( function() {
    alert('hao');
});
```

If you want to detect a change in content, I would advise using a `setInterval` or assign a value of a hidden input whenever the `h1` tag is changed.

Do you need an example?

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange` event can only be bound to input fields, textboxes and select menus - see [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/). Can you not handle this when you make the change to the h1?